# Get absolute path of a file [Android]

Tags: java, file, android-studio, storage

I have an app in which I write a file into the apps file folder(with a Fileoutputstream).
When i want to access it again I use a Bufferedreader with the location:

"data/data/com.mycomp.myapp.rstats/files/stats".

This works on pretty much all devices because the app gets installed there. But I imagine if somebody puts it on an external SD card, the path will be different. How can i get the absolute path of the file location?

Answer (score 1):

You can use.. But do check for storage type exist before use it.

```
File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```